# Pandas: How to check if any row in the index meets the a condition

Tags: python, pandas

Given example df:

```
index1  index2  value
a       1       5
a       1       4
a       2       2
b       1       1
b       1       1
b       2       3
c       1       2
c       1       4
c       2       6
```

How to filter out by index 1, possibly similarly to df = df[df=...], all of the records which meet some condition in value?
Example: I need all the records in index1 where any of the records in index1 is greater than 4. Then the output should look like:

```
index1  index2  value
a       1       5
a       1       4
a       2       2
c       1       2
c       1       4
c       2       6
```

b was filtered out as none of its values met the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `index1, index2` are columns first filter `index1` matching condition and then filter original column by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = df[df['index1'].isin(df.loc[df['value'].gt(4), 'index1'])]
print (df1)
  index1  index2  value
0      a       1      5
1      a       1      4
2      a       2      2
6      c       1      2
7      c       1      4
8      c       2      6
```

Or use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `any` for test at least one match:

```
df1 = df[df['value'].gt(4).groupby(df['index1']).transform('any')]
```

If there is `MultiIndex`:

```
idx = df.index.get_level_values(0)
df2 = df[idx.isin(idx[df['value'].gt(4)])]
print (df2)
               value
index1 index2       
a      1           5
       1           4
       2           2
c      1           2
       1           4
       2           6
```

---

```
df[df['value'].gt(4).groupby(level=0).transform('any')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired output `df[df['value'] >= 4]`. If you want just the values of index1 from that, you can use `get_level_values` to treat it like a regular column. For example:

```
print(df[df['value'] >= 4]].index.get_level_values(0))
```

output:

```
Index(['a', 'a', 'c', 'c'], dtype='object', name='index1')
```